# pdfmake: Fixed Column Height

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I want to add text to a column and i would like that column to have a fixed height and width. I've managed to add a fixed width but i'm unable to add a fixed height.

Here's my code:

```
{
    columns:
    [
        {
            width: 200,
            height: 300, //doesn't work...
            text: someText
        }
    ],
    absolutePosition:
    {
        x: 150,
        y: 75
    }
},
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if works for what you need but, you can use `maxHeight`.